# sending ping with specific bytes amount using c#

Tags: c#, .net

how can i send a ping request with a specific size of bytes, the same as determining the
-l when sending ping through the command line.
can you give me an example?

also can i determine the amount of packets that the ping sends? like the -n on the command line.

thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) class to send [ICMP echo requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping#Echo_request). It gives you complete control over the packet size and the number of packets sent:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public void PingHost(string host, int packetSize, int packetCount)
{
    int timeout = 1000;  // 1 second timeout.
    byte[] packet = new byte[packetSize];
    // Initialize your packet bytes as you see fit.

    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    for (int i = 0; i < packetCount; ++i) {
        pinger.Send(host, timeout, packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway the code example is wrong. You will send as many pings as the size of the packet witch is wrong. You have to compare inside the for against totalSends.

Answer (score 0):

Ping message is sent using the ICMP using System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class.
Here is simple example to send ping message to specific IP or Website.
If you do not send your specific byte array, .Net automatically sent it's own byte array.

Example :

```
    Ping objPing = new Ping();

    try
    {
        PingReply objReply = objPing.Send(txtURL.Text, 1000);

        if (objReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            lblProductName.Text = string.Format("<b>Success</b> - IP Address:{0} Time:{1}ms", objReply.Address, objReply.RoundtripTime);
        }
        else
        {
            lblProductName.Text = objReply.Status.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblProductName.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: Do not roll back Mod edits that remove your spammy links again.